# Json Array response doesn't see value for item

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I Know at first glance it's known mistake made by beginners but: 
My standard response looks like this:

```
 public ArrayList<Beer> jsonResponse(){
    beerList.clear();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            Constants.BASE_API_URL + Constants.BEER_LIST_URL_ENDPOINT,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {


                            JSONObject beerJsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            System.out.println(response.toString());
                            Beer beer = new Beer();
                            if (beerJsonObject.has("yeast")) {
                                beer.setYeast(beerJsonObject.getString("yeast"));
                            }

                            beer.setName(beerJsonObject.getString("name"));
                            beer.setIbu(beerJsonObject.getString("ibu"));
                            beer.setAlc(beerJsonObject.getString("abv"));
                            beer.setImgUrl(beerJsonObject.getString("image_url"));
                            beer.setId(beerJsonObject.getString("id"));
                            beer.setDescription(beerJsonObject.getString("description"));
                            beer.setFoodPairing(beerJsonObject.getString("food_pairing"));
                            beer.setFirstBrewed(beerJsonObject.getString("first_brewed"));
                            System.out.println(beer.getName()+" "+beer.getIbu()+" "+beer.getImgUrl());
                            beerList.add(beer);

                        }
                        beerRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
    );
    // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    return beerList;
}
```

Everything works except "yeast" item:

```
if (beerJsonObject.has("yeast")) {
                            beer.setYeast(beerJsonObject.getString("yeast"));
                        }
```

without that if statement I've got standard json err. response no value for "yeast", I thought maybe not every object in response has this value and added that. But that doesn't helped, I still can't get that value, like it wouldn't exist in array, but it's not true, even in System.out.println(response.toString()) I can see a lot of "yeast" .

Here is example response from API I'm working with: https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers

Comment: `yeast` is in the `ingredients` object, not the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yeast` is under `ingredients`

so should be:

```
if (beerJsonObject.has("ingredients")) {
   JSONObject ingredients = beerJsonObject.getJSONObject("ingredients");
   if (ingredients.has("yeast")) {
       beer.setYeast(ingredients.getString("yeast"));
   }
}
```